# Properly sizing view in -loadView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I'm having a problem getting my view to be sized properly when created via `-loadView`.  It seems that my view frame is always (0, 0, 320, 460), even when the view/controller is nested inside a UINavigationController and/or UITabBarController.  Is there a way to detect programmatically when my view controller is nested within these items, so that I can set the proper frame?  My loadView is just setting up a nested UIScrollView that should match exactly the visible size on the screen (460px is too tall when there is a tab bar and nav bar visible).

The reason I'm not hardcoding these values is that I would like this view controller to be reusable and work in all scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few properties of in [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that might be of interest here:

- navigationController
- tabBarController

If these are not `nil` you should be able to tell if you need to resize your view or not.

Comment: That's definitely a workable option. I would only be hesitant to use this because it would mean hardcoding frame sizes into my view controller based on the presence of tabBarController and navigationController - what happens when I want to port this to iPad or another device with a different screen size?

Comment: I think you are worrying too much about 'other' devices here really. So far there is only one other device and that is the iPad which will have a much larger screen so you would probably need to redesign the views anyway. :)

Comment: Each of those controllers has properties to get to the tabBar and/or navigationBar, which you can get the sizes from to deduce the proper remaining size for your screen...

Comment: +1 Kendall (also +1 OP), that sounds like the best option. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do not layout your views in loadView: or viewDidload: without a nib. Do it in viewWillAppear:, the main view's frame is properly at that time.

Comment: This is not totally reliable, as animations may not have been committed. (Example: Animate away the status bar then do a modal presentation of your view controller.)